# How to change unicode format while using get_text() in beautiful soup

Tags: python, unicode, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am getting unicode format while using get_text().
How do I change Unicode to string in DataFrame?

Need proper text format for tidy data.....
Below is my code....

```
import requests
from pattern import web
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import *
url = 'http://www.mouthshut.com/product-reviews/amazonin-reviews-925670774-srch'
    r = requests.get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    mouthrev = []
    Title = []
    for revlist in  bs.find_all("li","reviewdetails openshare"):
        title = revlist.find_all('div','reviewtitle fl')
        title = [g.get_text(strip=True) for g in title]

        for parent in revlist.find_all("div", itemprop='description'):
            review = parent.find_all('p')
            review = [g.get_text(strip=True) for g in review]
            mouthrev.append(review)
            Title.append(title)


    mouth1 = DataFrame({'Title' : Series(Title),'Review' : Series(mouthrev)})
    mouth1.to_csv('D:\\Review.csv')
```

I am getting result :

```
Title   Review
[u'Wrong product need immediate refund']    [u'I have been shopping with amazon for almost 6 months now and for the 1st time I ordered a Tuxedo. Looking at the item online it seemed perfect. My actual size for the suit is 40 which fits me perfectly. I ordered for the same size. Firstly the delivery didnt happen though I received a text statin ...']
[u'Cheating customers by sending a dummy tracking no.'] [u'Order #171-0709329-6021113( amazon.in)', u'I have placed this order on 15th Jan 2015 and I received a mail from amazon on 15th Jan 2015 itself as my order has shipped. Also I have received a tracking number of Speed Post.', u'Today it is 03rd Feb 2015, till now there is no status/details a...']
[u'BAD in Delivery. Unpredictable delivery date/time.'] [u'If Ordering from Amazon.In, be prepared for Delivery nightmares.', u'The Delivery team does NOT call you up before coming.', u'Amazon does send you Courier persons name and mobile. My experience has been is that this information is not reliable(Happened to me twice that the Delivery person I  ...']
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understood you correct why don't you use str()

```
review = [str(g.get_text(strip=True)) for g in review]
```

this will work

Comment: It isn't working....

I am getting this below error...
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x92' in position 144: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with Unicode. `[...]` is the representation (`repr`) of a list. You have a list in each cell because you're fetching the texts of multiple `p` elements:

```
title = [g.get_text(strip=True) for g in title]
review = [g.get_text(strip=True) for g in review]
```

If you want to form a single string from that you could join together multiple `p` texts as lines, eg:

```
review = '\n'.join(g.get_text(strip=True) for g in review)
```

and then the CSV formatter will have a string rather than a list, so it won't have to try to coerce the data to a string via `repr`.

Comment: Yes, It is working. But why can't  I save final result as csv file?
Is there way to save as csv ?

Comment: What happens when you try to save CSV? If you want to include non-ASCII characters in a CSV file you'll have to indicate when encoding you want, eg `.to_csv(filepath, encoding='utf-8')`. Note if you are targeting Excel it has its own sad problems reading non-ASCII characters.